# Kext compiled fine with symbols undefined

Tags: c++, macos, clang, kernel-extension

I am recently writing a kernel module for osx 10.9, and found out that every symbol in the final binary I compiled is undefined by nm tool.

How is it done by specifying flags in build settings? I mean, when you are building a user mode application, it cant be linked correctly when it has symbols unresolved. I cant find any related flags in command line of building the kext binary.

Just out of cuirosity, where is this flag that tells linker any undefined symbols are ok? I know the --unresolved-symbols flag but it is not found in the build command line.

Moreover, how do I link directly against mach_kernel? Cause I just saw a driver of osx 10.5 which links to macho. Or is it only possible in the old days?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The flag that accomplishes this for a kext is the `-Xlinker -kext`, it also includes the option `-nostdlib` because the base standard library is not available to a kext. These rules tell the OSX linker that it doesn't need to resolve all the symbols in the resulting binary.

You **don't** link directly to the kernel, you rely on the undefined symbols being connected up at kext load time rather than at any other time.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. XBinary from osx book has a kext that link against macho(mach_kernel). http://www.osxbook.com/software/xbinary/ It's for osx 10.5 leopard. Does old kext link directly? It didn't provide a source so there is nothing I can dig into.

Comment: The interface has changed quite a bit in 64bit, so I believe (but am open to correction) you can't link to it directly any more. You also need to define the kernel programming interface that you use in the `OSBundleLibraries` key of the kext's info.plist. You determine this by running `kextlibs` on the built kext.